# Check if string exists in list in one line?

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to do `git diff --name-only hash1 hash2`, and it gives something like:

```
package.json
index.ts
```

...listing the files.

How do I create a one-liner bash command to then check if it includes `package.json`?

```
git diff --name-only hash1 hash2 | includes package.json
```

Comment: Use something like `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep like this:

```
grep -Fxq package.json
```

- `-F` turns off regular expression matching so `package.json` doesn't match `packageXjson`, `packageYjson`, etc.
- `-x` turns off substring matching so `package.json` doesn't match `Xpackage.json`, `package.jsonY`, etc.
- and `-q` suppresses normal output so you get only whether there is a match or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77864371/how-to-grep-and-produce-true-if-match-otherwise-nothing-if-not-match-in-one

Comment: Hi @oguzismail: are the grep options: `-o` and `-w` similar to `-F` and `-x` or are they different ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep`. it returns non-zero when pattern not found.

```bash
if printf "1\n2" | grep -q ^2$; then echo in; else echo out; fi
```

See [grep(1) man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#EXIT_STATUS) for details.

Comment: You can use `grep -q` to suppress output if you're only interested in the exit code.