# How to grep and produce "true" if match, otherwise nothing if not match, in one line (bash)?

Tags: bash, grep

I have this so far:

```
echo "PACKAGE_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only abcabc abcabd | grep -Fqx package.json && echo \"true\")" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

I want it to be this if the package has changed:

```
PACKAGE_CHANGED=true
```

Otherwise to be this:

```
PACKAGE_CHANGED=
```

Or altogether omitted and doesn't do `>> $GITHUB_ENV` at all if it is false?

How can either of those be done in one line?

Because it didn't change in my specific attempt, I got:

```
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

If I change the package.json version, I get:

```
fatal: bad object ...ba669bfbf7c4c4defde782feae248c07f...
```

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Why are you doing `>> "$GITHUB_ENV"`? Just `echo "PACKAGE_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only abcabc abcabd | grep -Fqx package.json && echo 'true')"` should do the job

Comment: I need to have the string `PACKAGE_CHANGED=true` inside the `.env` file on GitHub Actions, which is stored under `$GITHUB_ENV`, so `echo stuff >> $GITHUB_ENV`.

Comment: Simply add `|| true` after the `echo` to avoid signaling an error.

Comment: You can change first command to `git diff --name-only abcabc abcabd 2>/dev/null`